# Is there an eclipse plugin that will show a log file output rather than stdin

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

My application writes most information to a log file, not STDIN, are there any eclipse plugins that would show one or more log files in a window like the Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you need something like [this tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logfiletools/)

Try it !

Answer (score 0):

Visit under Eclipse

```
Run =>  Run Configurations => Java Application => You Own Application => Common tab => File
```

Check *Append* for append mode.